# Python HTML scraping

Tags: python, html, regex, screen-scraping, html-content-extraction

It's not really scraping, I'm just trying to find the URLs in a web page where the class has a specific value. For example:

```
<a class="myClass" href="/url/7df028f508c4685ddf65987a0bd6f22e">
```

I want to get the href value. Any ideas on how to do this? Maybe regex? Could you post some example code?
I'm guessing html scraping libs, such as BeautifulSoup, are a bit of overkill just for this...

Huge thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Regex is usally a bad idea, try using [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)

Quick example:

```
html = #get html
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
links = soup.findAll('a', attrs={'class': 'myclass'})
for link in links:
    #process link
```

Comment: Nice one. BeautifulSoup FTW. Too bad it got worse in 3.0

Answer (score 9):

Aargh, not [regex for parsing HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)!

Luckily in Python we have [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) or [lxml](http://codespeak.net/lxml/) to do that job for us.

Answer (score 2):

Regex would be a bad choice. HTML is not a regular language. How about [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)?

Answer (score 1):

Regex should not be used to parse HTML.  See [the first answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) for an explanation :)

+1 for BeautifulSoup.

Answer (score 1):

If your task is just this simple, just use string manipulation (without even regex)

```
f=open("htmlfile")
for line in f:
    if "<a class" in line and "myClass" in line and "href" in line:
        s = line [ line.index("href") + len('href="') : ]
        print s[:s.index('">')]
f.close()
```

HTML parsers is not a must for such cases.

Answer (score 0):

read Parsing Html The Cthulhu Way https://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/

Answer (score 0):

The thing is I know the structure of the HTML page, and I just want to find that specific kind of links (where class="myclass"). BeautifulSoup anyway?