# How can I read an xml document/file into a DOM in python?

Tags: python, xml, dom, screen, screen-scraping

I need to do screen scraping and for that I need to read some xml from python. I want to get a proper DOM tree out of it. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [the minidom package](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.dom.minidom.html) which also has examples.

BTW if your screen scraping is HTML don't use XML parsing. There's other stuff for that.
([Question about screen scraping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861/options-for-html-scraping), [Question about python HTML screen scraping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793663/python-html-scraping)).

Comment: And there's other, more comfortable stuff than minidom, mainly the ElementTree API :)

Comment: I happen to like minidom. It works, and it's always included in Python. Easier to get it deployed that way, especially if the servers are maintained by others.

Answer (score 0):

The [lxml](http://codespeak.net/lxml/parsing.html) library works well for scraping HTML.  Here are some links to get you started:

- [Parsing XML and HTML with lxml](http://codespeak.net/lxml/parsing.html)
- [lxml: an underappreciated web scraping library](http://blog.ianbicking.org/2008/12/10/lxml-an-underappreciated-web-scraping-library/)